# 5 card straight in 7 card poker hand detection with list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, poker

I'm programming a 7 card poker hand evaluating script for learning purposes.
Currently programming the straight detection.

Although I've already found a working solution, it's not very 'pythonic' because it checks if it has an A-5 straight, then in another statement it checks the rest of the straights. Lame.

I've created a list of possible straights:

```py
#  01 = Deuce, 13 = Ace
STRAIGHTS = [sorted([13, *range(1,14)][n:n+5]) for n in range(0,10)]
```

This includes the pesky A-5 straight.

Now what I'm trying to do is intersect my hand with these lists and see if the length of this intersection is bigger than 5.

If I do this:

```py
if len([item for item in hand if item in [13,1,2,3,4]) >= 5
```

It works like a charm. But if I snap the STRAIGHTS list on the hard coded list there it doesn't work. Why is that?

```py
if len([item for item in hand if item in STRAIGHTS) >= 5
```

`else:`

Comment: in `[item for item in hand if item in STRAIGHTS]`, STRAIGHTS is a list of lists - so this list comprehension will only work *as I think it should* if item is also a list (which I assume is not the case so it doesn't work)

Comment: You could use list differences to  check for straights without hardcoding all possible straights

Comment: Well, it looks like there's lots of straight possibilities, but there's only 10 possibilities, and we can "hard code" it with a single list comprehension anyway.

Comment: Any straightforward poker hand evaluation algorithm (i.e., not one of those fancy algorithms with big lookup tables) is going to have to have an ugly special case for the wheel. Unless you make aces low, then you'll have an ugly special case for Broadway. No way around it.

Comment: actually @Simon 's solution with the straight lookup table worked like a charm, same statement for wheels and other straights :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your `hand` is a list of integers as well

```
if max([len(set(hand).intersection(set(s))) for s in STRAIGHTS]) >=5
```